# Providing a callback function as a specific pointertype

Tags: objective-c, pointers, networking, ssl

I am currently working on a Server in Objective-C on a Mac that listens on a specific port for incoming data. It already works for unencrypted data transfer based on NSStreams in both directions.

In the next step I would like to secure the connection via SSL/TLS. Currently I am following apple's approach described in their documentation on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html) page. In the *Overview* they describe a typical sequence to build a SSL connection.

Where I fail now is the point where I have to give a pointer of the form

```
typedef OSStatus (*SSLReadFunc) (
   SSLConnectionRef connection,
   void *data,
   size_t *dataLength
);
```

in a method that sets the I/O functions for the SSL-Connection such that the responsible object can call these methods for reading and writing on my streams. I already wrote the two methods

```
// Called by the secure transport to write data on the stream
-(OSStatus)sslWriteCallbackFunction:(SSLContextRef)context data:(const void *)data dataLength:(size_t)dataLength sizeOfProcessedData:(size_t *)processed{
    processed = (size_t *)[_writeStream write:data maxLength:dataLength];
    if (processed < 0)
        return errSSLProtocol;
    else if (processed==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return errSSLWouldBlock;
}

// Called by the secure transport to read data from the stream
-(OSStatus) sslReadCallbackFunction:(SSLContextRef)context data:(const void *)data dataLength:(size_t)dataLength{
    uint8_t buffer[dataLength];
    NSInteger err = [_readStream read:buffer maxLength:dataLength];

    if (err < 0)
        // Error
        return errSSLProtocol;
    else if (err==0)
        // All bytes have been read
        return 0;
    else
        // err corresponds to the number of bytes read, so there are still bytes available
        dataLength = err;
        return errSSLWouldBlock;
}
```

and would like to set them in the method with the signature

```
OSStatus SSLSetIOFuncs (
   SSLContextRef context,
   SSLReadFunc readFunc,
   SSLWriteFunc writeFunc
);
```

for the method `sslReadCallbackFunction` to be passed via `readFunc` and the write method respectively.

Now, how can I create a pointer to one of the two methods of the form described above. I have tried so much that I would be really grateful if someone could help me or point into the right direction. I used selectors, just a `&` in front of the method name, using a method of `self`,....

Any help is appreciated and please be aware of the fact that I am new to Objective-C ;)

Answer (score 0):

The API expects a pointer to C-functions with the given signature, rather than Objective-C methods. If you still want to handle the callbacks in methods, not functions, you need to use a "trampoline" function. This is a small function that simply calls through to the Objective-C method. Often callback functions include a user context pointer that you give to the API and which is passed to the function. This is handy because you can pass `self` in and use that to easily message the right ObjC instance. Something like this:

```
OSStatus MySSLReadCallbackFunction(SSLConnectionRef connection, void *data, size_t *ioDataLength)
{
    MySSLClass *obj = (__bridge MySSLClass *)connection
    return [obj sslReadFromConnection:connection intoBuffer:data length:ioDataLength];
}

// In the function that sets this stuff up:
SSLSetConnection(context, (__bridge void *)self);
SSLSetIOFuncs(context, MySSLReadCallbackFunction, MySSLWriteCallbackFunction);
```

Mark Dalrymple has a [good post](http://borkwarellc.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/c-callbacks-in-objc/) on his blog about this general problem.

Note that as mentioned in the comments on that article, it *is* possible to get a pointer to the underlying C function that implements an ObjC method. However, functions that implement ObjC methods have two "hidden" arguments (`self` and `_cmd`), so you can't force them to have the right signature for an API like this.

Comment: I think you can use the SSLConnectionRef for this purpose. It is an opaque pointer that can be associated with the SSLContextRef: `SSLSetConnection(context, (__bridge void *)self);`, and exactly that is passed to the callback functions, so `MySSLClass *obj = (__bridge MySSLClass*)connection;` should work.

Comment: Thanks Martin. That wasn't clear from my skim of the documentation, and I have no direct experience with this API. I edited my answer to include this.